# How to change attribute title

Tags: dropdown-attribute

Hi recently I have create a dropdown attribute,now client need to change the title of attribute I have tried to change title from catalog->manage Attribute->Manage Attribute->Manage Label/options->In Manage Title

But my changed title is not reflecting in front end.

Can you please let me know how I can do this from admin section?

Comment: Hopefully I'm not stating the obvious but have you flushed the cache under System > Cache Management, and also reindexed (specifically Product Attributes Index) under System > Index Management?

Comment: have you multi store ?

Answer (score 0):

You can edit it in mysql at **eav_attribute.attribute_code**. Be sure to take backups prior and re-index all in **System>Index Management** afterwards.